# How to access ASP.NET drop down box from jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Well, I have a really small problem. How can I access an ASP.NET Drop down list from jquery? I tried to use "CssClass" property of the drop down list to assign a CSS class and then accessing that list using that class, but later I found out that the class changes when an element is selected, so my initial class replaced by a new class.I set the "CssClass" property of that list to "InstrumentDropDown". When the page loads for the first time, its class property is set to "InstrumentDropDown", just as I expected. But when an element is selected, and a postback is made, it becomes something like "InstrumentDropDown sg selected" (may be there are underscore between words instead of spaces)

I also cannot use the "ClientID" property because the part of code that access that list is not inside the page, but in a separate javascript file.

So how can I access it ?

Comment: check how does asp:dropdownlist  rendered. I mean just look over the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page loads, use the class to find the dropdown box and store the id of the element in a variable.

```
 $(function() {
      var $ddl = $('select.myClass'); // get here

      $('.somethingelse').click( function() {
            $.get('...',function(data) {
                $ddl.html(data);  // use here
            }
      }
 });
```

Comment: If I do that, then when the second time the "click" event fires, will "$ddl" contain that class value? If it is the case, then why? Isn't it a local variable which will be destroyed when the function execution is finished ?

Comment: $ddl is captured inside the click handler.  Whenever the click handler is executed, it will use the value originally assigned to $ddl.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing I can think of is wrap your Drop Down List inside a element with another id. That way, you can reference it like this rather than worrying about ASP.NET ClientIDs.

Script:

```
$('#dropDown select');
```

Markup:

```
<div id="dropDown">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, that will certainly do the trick. It also came to my mind, but I wanted to know if there is any other way, without using that extra "div" just to access a list. Also I wanted to know the general practice.

Comment: If your not using MVC then the id selector will not work, due to naming containers. You should use class names instead of id's when working with Web Forms. Or, you could use the id selecting syntax that @Nick Craver used below.

Comment: @xandercoded -- note the div is not `runat=server` so the name is not mangled.

Comment: This will work in Web Forms, the div tag ID will remain unchanged because it is plain html (not runat="server").

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one of the dropdown on the page and you're sure of this, you can also find it by ID using the [attribute ends-with selector ($=)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), like this:

```
$("[id$=dropDownID]")
```

This would for example find: `<select id="MasterPage$Content$dropDownID">`

Comment: Nope, it is not the only drop down in the page.

Comment: @Sayem - There are multiple with this same ID? e.g. in various user controls?

Answer (score 1):

In the case the `CssClass` name changes `OnPostback` this selector will work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   $('select.InstrumentDropDown_sg_selected, select.InstrumentDropDown').change(function(){
      var yourValue = $(this).val(); //retrieve value
      $(this).val('someValue'); //set value
   });

});
```